# No request params in constraint when testing route

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, routes

When I run this in practice it works, but I can't seem to write a working test for my route constraint with rspec.

When the test runs the constraint is triggered, but the request params are empty, thus it does not validate and the test fails.

I am running Rails 3.0.9, rspec-rails 2.6.1 and rspec 2.6.0.

**config/routes.rb**

```
match ":param1-unique-:param2" => "controller#index",
  :constraints => ParamConstraint.new
```

**lib/param_constraint.rb**

```
class ParamConstraint
  def matches?(request)
    @request ||= request
    valid_param1? && valid_param2?
  end

  def valid_param1?
    @request.params[:param1] == "lorem"
  end

  def valid_param2?
    @request.params[:param2] == "ipsum"
  end
end
```

**spec/routing/param_constraint_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "param constraint routing" do
  it "recognizes route for param1 and param2" do
    { :get => "/lorem-unique-ipsum" }.
      should route_to(
        :controller => "controller",
        :action => "index",
        :param1 => "lorem",
        :param2 => "ipsum"
      )
  end
end
```

### Update

If I inspect the request in the constraint I get the following output:

```
#<ActionDispatch::Request:0x007fee140ff910 @env={
  "rack.version"=>[1, 1],
  "rack.input"=>#<StringIO:0x007fee1446da48>,
  "rack.errors"=>#<StringIO:0x007fee1446e768>,
  "rack.multithread"=>true,
  "rack.multiprocess"=>true,
  "rack.run_once"=>false,
  "REQUEST_METHOD"=>"GET",
  "SERVER_NAME"=>"example.org",
  "SERVER_PORT"=>"80",
  "QUERY_STRING"=>"",
  "PATH_INFO"=>"/lorem-unique-ipsum",
  "rack.url_scheme"=>"http",
  "HTTPS"=>"off",
  "SCRIPT_NAME"=>"",
  "CONTENT_LENGTH"=>"0"
}>
```

Comment: What do you have inside `matches?`? I mean have you debugged @request?

Comment: Yes, if I run `Rails.logger.info @request.params.inspect` I get an empty hash. And I have updated my post with the inspected `@request`.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same issue today, searching for an answer brought me to this page's question. For what it's worth, I had to resort to writing a request spec instead.

```
context "passing params that satisfy ParamConstraint" do
  before do
    visit "/lorem-unique-ipsum"
  end
  it "should serve up a page with content" do
    # replace this with some assertion that gets satisfied by
    # pages served up when ParamConstraint.new.matches? returns true
    page.should have_selector("html body div#foo")
    page.should_not have_selector("html body div#bar")
  end
 end
context "passing params that DO NOT satisfy ParamConstraint" do
  before do
    visit "/other-unique-other"
  end
  it "should serve up a page with different content" do
    # replace this with some assertion that gets satisfied by
    # pages served up when ParamConstraint.new.matches? returns false
    page.should_not have_selector("html body div#foo")
    page.should have_selector("html body div#bar")
  end
 end
```

This doesn't answer your question, which I take to be "how to test routing constraint", as the proper way would be via a routing spec. But given this gap in how request.params works when you use "should route_to", this is a workaround.  A request spec, as opposed to a routing spec, will fill request.params correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue exists years later, with rspec-core 3.4.4, rspec-rails 3.4.2, rails 4.2.6.  Don't have time to dig into exactly why...

You can use a request spec as suggested above, but don't use it to test the page contents.  Instead, replicate a routing test (`route_to`) by checking the conversion of URL paths to request params:

```
RSpec.describe 'routes', type: :request do
  describe '/:slug' do
    it 'routes correctly' do
      get '/test-product-slug'
      expect(request.params).to eq(
        'controller' => 'product',
        'action' => :index,
        'slug' => 'test-product-slug'
      )
    end
  end
end
```